# Copy conditional formatting based on cell content to other rows

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

I have a sheet which contains all usernames and email addresses of my database

In another sheet i have a column saying "username", in here I want to enter usernames, if a username entered here is already in the list on the other sheet the field content should change color to red.

I figured out how to do conditional formatting on the cell, so I made this formula:

```
=COUNTIF('Usernames and emails'!A5:A1450;$A$7)>0
```

This formula works great for the cell in A7.

However when I drag A7 all the way to the bottom of my table, the conditional formatting formula is not copied. When i for example type in the same username in A8 as i did in A7, the A7 field would turn red but A8 would remain unchanged.

I need this formatting on about 1000+ fields, so making a rule for every single one of them cannot be the solution?

Example:

Worksheet : Usernames and emails:

```
test1
test2
test3
```

Worksheet : i have to enter usernames in every row in the A column, so i enter them like this:

```
A1 : test
A2 : test1
A3 : test4
A4 : test3
```

in this example, A2 and A4 should be colored in red since they have a value that corresponds to a value in my "usernames and emails" worksheet list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Select the range you want to apply the conditional formatting to. In this case it seems to be A7:A1007. A7 should be the 'active cell'.
- Use this formula to create the Conditional Formatting Rule:
   
        `=countif('Usernames and emails'!$A$5:$A$1450; $A7)`
   
    Note `$A$5:$A$1450` instead of `A5:A1450` and `$A7` instead of `$A$7`.

Answer (score 2):

According to [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/2xa9fs/highlighting_duplicate_values_across_multiple/), you can use

```
=MATCH(A1,'Usernames and emails'!A:A,0)
```

I tested this on some made up data and it worked (though note that some people in that thread seem to have had some issues).

Aside for that, you should probably anchor your whole range, and not the comparative cell, thus:

```
=COUNTIF('Usernames and emails'!$A$5:$A$1450;$A7)>0
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am unsure on how to use the duplicate values, because the values entered in my second sheet still need to be entered by me, so I want the formatting to update whenever i enter the value and go to another cell and i notice that what I entered is a duplicate of any entry in the list in my first worksheet

Comment: Could you just select the entire column and apply the formatting?

Comment: If i use the method you suggest, highlight my predefined values in my first worksheet, click CTRL and select the column of 1000 rows where I want my values to be entered. Then go to formatting and select "duplicate values", the cells will only apply that formatting when I entered the exact same value twice in my second worksheet, regardless of what is in the list of my first worksheet

Comment: I also seem to have a problem using that solution, it does not work as intended... Solution of Jeeped below did the trick though, thanks!

Comment: I mentioned the same thing as he did in the second half of my answer ;) But all good, glad it worked out for you!